# Can I use '&' shorthand for selecting matches?

Tags: ruby, block, proc

I have this code:

```
result=
["MA-1", "NY-2", "CT-2", "NJ-1", "NJ-2", "NJ-3"].select do |element|
  element.match '2'
end
```

Is there a way to use the `&` shortcut without using a separate proc?

I tried:

```
["MA-1", "NY-2", "CT-2", "NJ-1", "NJ-2", "NJ-3"].select(&:match('2'))
```

which raises a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you can use `grep`:

```
["MA-1", "NY-2", "CT-2", "NJ-1", "NJ-2", "NJ-3"].grep(/2/)
#=> ["NY-2", "CT-2", "NJ-2"]
```

Or with the custom proc:

```
my_proc = ->(e) { e.match('2') }
["MA-1", "NY-2", "CT-2", "NJ-1", "NJ-2", "NJ-3"].select(&my_proc)
#=> ["NY-2", "CT-2", "NJ-2"]
```

Or (credits to @engineersmnky):

```
select(&/2/.method(:match))
```

Comment: yeah, `grep` is a great tool. I don't use it enough.

Answer (score 2):

> [can I do this] without using a separate proc

No. Primarily because neither `&` nor symbols are methods or anything that can accept parameters. You must use the full form.